# Add Rows on Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I'd like to know which is the preferred way to add records to a database table in a Rails Migration. I've read on Ola Bini's book (Jruby on Rails) that he does something like this:

```
class CreateProductCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration

  #defines the AR class
  class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base; end

  def self.up

    #CREATE THE TABLES...

    load_data
  end
  def self.load_data
    #Use AR object to create default data
    ProductType.create(:name => "type")
  end
end
```

This is nice and clean but for some reason, doesn't work on the lasts versions of rails...

The question is, how do you populate the database with default data (like users or something)?

Thanks!

Comment: That is pretty much what I do, please include the error you are receiving.

Comment: The full code is this: http://pastie.org/pastes/251539

And the error is 'CreateProductCategories is not missing constant ProductType'

Comment: Use seeds.rb for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use fixtures for that.  It means having a yaml file somewhere with the data you want to insert.

Here is a changeset I committed for this in one of my app:

`db/migrate/004_load_profiles.rb`

```
require 'active_record/fixtures'

class LoadProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    down()

    directory = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "init_data")
    Fixtures.create_fixtures(directory, "profiles")
  end

  def self.down
    Profile.delete_all
  end
end
```

`db/migrate/init_data/profiles.yaml`

```
admin:
 name: Admin
  value: 1
normal:
 name: Normal user
  value: 2
```

Answer (score 42):

The Rails API documentation for migrations shows a simpler way to achieve this.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

```
class CreateProductCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table "product_categories" do |t|
      t.string name
      # etc.
    end

    # Now populate the category list with default data

    ProductCategory.create :name => 'Books', ...
    ProductCategory.create :name => 'Games', ... # Etc.

    # The "down" method takes care of the data because it
    # drops the whole table.

  end

  def self.down
    drop_table "product_categories"
  end
end
```

Tested on Rails 2.3.0, but this should work for many earlier versions too.

Comment: Recommended way is to use seeds.rb.

Comment: Yes, but only for the initial data in a clean database. Seeds aren't appropriate when you have an existing data set, then add or change functionality in a way that needs some new records to be loaded into the database up-front *in addition to* any existing data. For that, you probably need a migration.

I also note that the jury is still out on the standard Rails seed mechanism!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761123/what-is-the-best-way-to-seed-a-database-in-rails

Comment: more RoR oriented: 
create_table :product_categories
drop_table :product_categories

Answer (score 7):

You could also define in your seeds.rb file, for instance:

```
Grid.create :ref_code => 'one' , :name => 'Grade Única'
```

and after run:

```
rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 4):

your migrations have access to all your models, so you shouldn't be creating a class inside the migration.

I am using the latest rails, and I can confirm that the example you posted definitely OUGHT to work.

However, migrations are a special beast.  As long as you are clear, I don't see anything wrong with an `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO product_types (name) VALUES ('type1'), ('type2')")`.

The advantage to this is, you can easily generate it by using some kind of GUI or web front-end to populate your starting data, and then doing a `mysqldump -uroot database_name.product_types`.

Whatever makes things easiest for the kind of person who's going to be executing your migrations and maintaining the product.

Answer (score 1):

You should really not use

```
ProductType.create
```

in your migrations.

I have done similar but in the long run they are not guaranteed to work.

When you run the migration the model class you are using is the one at the time you run the migration, not the one at the time you created the migration.  You will have to be sure you never change your model in such a way to stop you migration from running.

You are much better off running SQL for example:

```
[{name: 'Type', ..}, .. ].each do |type|
  execute("INSERT INTO product_types (name) VALUES ('#{type[:name]} .. )
end
```