# Ruby on Rails migrations are very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, performance, sqlite

I have SQLite3 database, which is populated with some large set of data.
I use migration for that.

3 tables will have following count of records:
Table_1 will have about 10 records
   each record of Table_1 will be associated with ~100 records in Table_2
      each record of Table_2 will be associated with  ~2000 records in Table_3

The count of records will be about 10*100*2000 = 2000000

This takes a long time... Event, if i populate my database with about 20000 records, it takes about 10 minutes.

Also, i have noticed, that, during migration execution, ruby interpreter takes just 5% from CPU time and 95% remains unused ...

What the reason of such pure performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, inserting large amounts of records through manually saving AR objects one at a time is going to take years.

The best compromise between speed and "cleanness" (i.e. not a complete dodgy hack) for inserting large amounts of data is ar-extensions's (http://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions) import method. It's not ideal, but it's better than any of the alternatives I could find, and the syntax is clean and doesn't require you to drop to raw sql (or anywhere close).

Example syntax:

```
items = Array.new
1.upto(200) do |n|
  items << Item.new :some_field => n
end
Item.import items, :validate => false
```

At least in mysql this will batch the records into a single INSERT statement with multiple sets of values. Pretty damn fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you run each `INSERT` statement in it's own transaction, SQLite can be very, very slow.  But if you run it all in one transaction (or a logical set of transactions), then it can be very fast.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail - how i can flush all prepared data in one transaction. I use Ruby on Rails to generate some data randomly (for testing purposes).
I only know the ActiveRecord:Base.save() method, but, as far, as i know, it must be called for each created object, but not for the whole model ... or ?

Answer (score 0):

[Seed_fu](http://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) could help, as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761123/what-is-the-best-way-to-seed-a-database-in-rails)