# Ranked Model getting started

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the `gem 'ranked-model'` in Rails 3.2.

This is the model:

```
class Costproject < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RankedModel
  scope :active, where("coststatus_id IN (?)", [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ).where("project_year = ?", Time.now.year + 1)
  ranks :row_order,
        :scope => :active
```

I ran this in the Rails console:

```
Costproject.rank(:row_order).all
```

After, the column `row_order` is blank in all the records.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

I believe now that `Costproject.rank(:row_order).all` is used to list the projects.  I thought it was a command to seed the numbers in the list.  Maybe I don't have to do that?

Comment: can you paste the SQL commands that `Costproject.rank(:row_order).all` returns?

Comment: I'm starting to think that `Costproject.rank(:row_order).all` is not meant to seed the numbers.  That's what I thought it was for.

Comment: I now believe it's to return the list in row_order

Comment: oh yeah! you'd want to seed your db before your use `rank`

Comment: devkaroru how exactly do I seed the list?  Where do I run `rank` or is it some other command?  (Make an answer and I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our conversation via comments. The problem looks like you need to `seed` your database before you can use the `rank` command.

So you can seed your dev database a few ways, via `rails console`, using your app or modifying your `seeds.rb` file.

I'm going to suggest you use your `seeds.rb` file because it's idempotent ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence )

So open `db/seeds.rb` or create one if you don't have one.

Create a few records:

```
Costproject.create(rank_order: 3, coststatus_id: 2, project_year: 2016)
Costproject.create(rank_order: 2, coststatus_id: 2, project_year: 2016)
Costproject.create(rank_order: 1, coststatus_id: 2, project_year: 2016)
```

This will insert 3 records into `costprojects` table. You **MUST** have the coststatus_id and project_year set to those values per your *scope*. These won't work:

```
Costproject.create(rank_order: 10)
Costproject.create(rank_order: 20, coststatus_id: 10)
Costproject.create(rank_order: 30, coststatus_id: 2, project_year: 2013)
```

then via terminal you can run:

```
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

This rake task will run your seed file as if you were manually typing it in your `rails console`.

Now you should be able to do `Costproject.rank(:row_order).all`. The first model *should* have an id of `3`, assuming you ran your seed file on an empty database.

For more info:

[What is the best way to seed a database in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761123/what-is-the-best-way-to-seed-a-database-in-rails)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

http://www.jasonwieringa.com/rake_rails_and_databases/