# ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column posts.user_id does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, pg

my code is working fine on my system in development mode but when i pushed to heroku, i am getting this error on the logs.

i'm on Rails 5.2.3 & ruby 2.3.3

ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column posts.user_id does not exist

LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1

**On heroku console, when i try to retrieve user_id i get**

```
irb(main):001:0> p = Post.last
  Post Load (11.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> p.user_id
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass)
irb(main):003:0>  !    ECONNRESET: read ECONNRESET
```

### but on development i get

```
irb(main):001:0> p =Post.last
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Post id: 13, description: "#snopp", user_id: 1, created_at: "2019-05-02 15:38:09", updated_at: "2019-05-02 15:38:09", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> p.user_id
=> 1
irb(main):003:0>
```

this is my schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_05_02_123348) do

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.integer "record_id", null: false
    t.integer "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "hash_tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "post_hash_tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "hash_tag_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["hash_tag_id"], name: "index_post_hash_tags_on_hash_tag_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_post_hash_tags_on_post_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "image_file_name"
    t.string "image_content_type"
    t.bigint "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "website"
    t.text "bio"
    t.integer "phone"
    t.string "gender"
    t.string "avatar"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

### Post Model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    after_commit :create_hash_tags, on: :create

    has_many :post_hash_tags
    has_many :hash_tags, through: :post_hash_tags



    belongs_to :user
end
```

### user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable

         has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: On production, you have not created anything in the `posts` table. `Post.last == nil`.

Comment: The error does not say `posts.user_id does not exist`. The error says `undefined method 'user_id' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: when i try posts/new i get  ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'user_id' for Post.)

Comment: It looks like you have no posts in the database.  Try running `Post.count`, my guess is that will return `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
heroku pg:reset
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
```

There is no instances of `Post` which gives you the error of `NilClass`. You can seed the database as suggested in the other post. For more information about seeding a database check the [rails docs on seeding.](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)

Comment: The error doesn't indicate this is the solution. If there were no posts table the error would be `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR`

Comment: is giving `undefined method 'user_id' for nil:NilClass` which means Heroku logs that error since there is no `Post` instance. Even thought the class is there

Comment: @lacostenycoder you see!, you down voted a correct answer.

Comment: @bottles if is correct you mind upvoting the solution.

Comment: this is what community is all about! Thanks for the feedback @lacostenycoder your input was more in-depth. I clearly understand now why you wanted the correction on seeds.

Comment: @StevenAguilar also, beware that `heroku pg:reset` will basically destroy the existing db, which might NOT be what the OP wants and is a bit heavy handed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820549/how-to-empty-a-heroku-database

Answer (score 2):

To test your application on Heroku which we would assume is running in production mode, you'll probably want to seed the production database.

You should have a `db/seeds.rb` file where you can do this.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761123/what-is-the-best-way-to-seed-a-database-in-rails) for ways you can use it.
Also see [Rails Docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) for ideas.

If you build your seeds with seeds.rb file you should be able to run

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate. I'm gonna look into that

Answer (score 0):

not sure if we can set automated migration while deploying to the heroku,
but once the code is deployed to the heroku you need to run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and your problem will be solved.